# Is there a way for Typescript to detect correct overloaded function on composition?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

While playing with FP in Typescript I moved to overloaded functions and now have a problem of Typescript not detecting the correct overloaded parameter types.

```js
/** parses as `Date` instance */
export function asDate(val: string | number | Date): Date;
export function asDate(val: string | number | Date | null | undefined): Date | null;
export function asDate(val: unknown) {
  return val instanceof Date ? val : typeof val === 'number' || typeof val === 'string' ? new Date(val) : null;
}

export function apply<T, R>(fn: (arg: T) => R) {
  return fn;
}

const date0 = asDate(123); // detected as Date
const date1 = apply(asDate)(123); // detected as Date | null
```

I would expect `date1` to infer that it is called with a `number` and detect return type `Date` but it takes the most open type and detects `Date | null` instead. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Not strictly related, but the second variant should be written this way: export function asDate(val: null | undefined): null;

Comment: Typescript supports function overloading but with same number of parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is possible although I'm not quite sure why your approach does not work.

It works by letting the compiler infer the type of the passed function:

```
export function apply<F extends (args: any) => any>(fn: F) {
    return fn;
}
```

In the end:

```
/** parses as `Date` instance */
export function asDate(val: string | number | Date): Date;
export function asDate(val: null | undefined): null;
export function asDate(val: unknown) {
    return val instanceof Date ? val : typeof val === 'number' || typeof val === 'string' ? new Date(val) : null;
}

export function apply<F extends (args: any) => any>(fn: F) {
    return fn;
}

const date0 = asDate(123); // detected as Date
const date1 = apply(asDate)(123); // detected as Date
const date3 = apply(asDate)(null); // detected as null
const date4 = apply(asDate)(true); // TS2769: No overload matches this call
```

Comment: Thx, though it feels really strange that this one works. If I do the same type in `fn` directly in the parameter instead of generic `F` it stops working. But this should be enough to get me going.